# fyneworks Multiple File Upload - Add a description textbox after upload selection

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins

I am using fyneworks Multiple File Upload tool ( http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/ ) to select multiple files for upload in ASP.NET. and it is working as expected.. but my requirement is, after i choose something to upload i need to show a textbox in the list next to it to add description about the upload .. how can i do this ??

here is the image of what i am able to do[image]

and what i need is a textbox after every list. ie 1.png 2.png etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only a jQuery plugin to add files. It does not assist at the server side.

You could modify the plugin to add a textarea for each file. Identifying the row level class and appending a textarea is really simple in jQuery.

The main problem you will face is with receiving this data in your asp.net code.
You will have to dynamically create controls(TextBoxes would work) depending on the number of files.

Comment: continuing with the same question, is it possible to allow to upload all file extensions except .exe and .vb ????

Comment: You can use the accept attribute `accept="image/gif,image/png"`. IE doesn't support this though.

Comment: I'm the developer of the plugin and I'd just like to point out first and foremost that *server-side validation is ALWAYS required*.

But you can configure the plugin to pre-emptively reject some files based on their extension.